# Possible to pass more than 1 argument to a context processor in Django?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to pass more than 1 argument to a context processor in Django? In other words, in addition to the HttpRequest object, I would like to pass 1 or more additional argument?

Comment: pass from where? what's your desired use-case?

Comment: I have an explore bar that displays on every page. My site is divided into e.g. 4 countries that have the same type of pages. The explore bar should look the same for different countries except display different country specific navigation links. So I would like to pass the country to my "explore bar context processor" in order to display the different links depending on which country is currently being navigated.

Comment: either use a template tag and fill the variable in the template using data from the view, or store it in the session and access it inside the request object inside the context processor

Answer (score 2):

Store whatever variables you would want in the session. Then you can access it through the request.

Comment: This was exactly my thought. It's dead simple and doesn't require anything to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into custom tags:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags

Make sure that your template tags module is in a `templatetags` subdir of a loaded module. I.e. if you have a "foo" module in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, make sure that, wherever foo is located, there is a:

```
foo/templatetags/blurf.py
```

that contains the tags and filters you want. Then you can:

```
{% load blurf %}
```

in your template, and if blurf has a `grok` tag with two arguments defined, then you can:

```
{% grok 1 2 %}
```

in that template.

Comment: @sizeight: did you end up using templatetags?